# Cómo solucionar error ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

Tags: python-3.x, opengl

estoy empezando a aprender sobre Pyglet y OpenGl y tengo este código que estoy investigando pero no logro que funcione. Estoy utilizando python 3.10.3 y python 3.6 dándome error en cualquiera de los dos. El código se escribió originalmente para python 2.7.
Realmente no entiendo lo que está pasando ya que lo que se espera en `glGetUniformLocation(self.handle, name), *vals` es un entero y es lo que está recibiendo.

el error que obtengo es este:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\Users\Toni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Palabras y kivyPruebas mas varios\varios\nombreStarWars\proyectos\juegovida\pruebas_de_codigo\opengl_prueba.py", line 71, in <module>    
        shader.uniformi('tex0', 0)
      File "c:\Users\Toni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Palabras y kivyPruebas mas varios\varios\nombreStarWars\proyectos\juegovida\pruebas_de_codigo\shader.py", line 125, in uniformi
        }[len(vals)](glGetUniformLocation(self.handle, name), *vals)
      File "C:\Users\Toni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\lib_wgl.py", line 103, in __call__
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Adjunto código.

archivo 1: opengl_prueba.py

```
#
# Copyright Tristam Macdonald 2008.
#
# Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0
# (see http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
#
 
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
 
from shader import Shader
 
# create the window, but keep it offscreen until we are done with setup
window = pyglet.window.Window(640, 480, resizable=True, visible=False, caption="Life")
 
# centre the window on whichever screen it is currently on (in case of multiple monitors)
print(int(window.screen.width/2 - window.width/2), int(window.screen.height/2 - window.height/2))
window.set_location(int(window.screen.width/2 - window.width/2), int(window.screen.height/2 - window.height/2))
print(window.screen.width/2 - window.width/2, window.screen.height/2 - window.height/2)
 
# create our shader
shader = Shader(['''
void main() {
    // transform the vertex position
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    // pass through the texture coordinate
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
}
'''], ['''
uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform vec2 pixel;
 
void main() {
    // retrieve the texture coordinate
    vec2 c = gl_TexCoord[0].xy;
 
    // and the current pixel
    vec3 current = texture2D(tex0, c).rgb;
 
    // count the neightbouring pixels with a value greater than zero
    vec3 neighbours = vec3(0.0);
    neighbours += vec3(greaterThan(texture2D(tex0, c + pixel*vec2(-1,-1)).rgb, vec3(0.0)));
    neighbours += vec3(greaterThan(texture2D(tex0, c + pixel*vec2(-1, 0)).rgb, vec3(0.0)));
    neighbours += vec3(greaterThan(texture2D(tex0, c + pixel*vec2(-1, 1)).rgb, vec3(0.0)));
    neighbours += vec3(greaterThan(texture2D(tex0, c + pixel*vec2( 0,-1)).rgb, vec3(0.0)));
    neighbours += vec3(greaterThan(texture2D(tex0, c + pixel*vec2( 0, 1)).rgb, vec3(0.0)));
    neighbours += vec3(greaterThan(texture2D(tex0, c + pixel*vec2( 1,-1)).rgb, vec3(0.0)));
    neighbours += vec3(greaterThan(texture2D(tex0, c + pixel*vec2( 1, 0)).rgb, vec3(0.0)));
    neighbours += vec3(greaterThan(texture2D(tex0, c + pixel*vec2( 1, 1)).rgb, vec3(0.0)));
 
    // check if the current pixel is alive
    vec3 live = vec3(greaterThan(current, vec3(0.0)));
 
    // resurect if we are not live, and have 3 live neighrbours
    current += (1.0-live) * vec3(equal(neighbours, vec3(3.0)));
 
    // kill if we do not have either 3 or 2 neighbours
    current *= vec3(equal(neighbours, vec3(2.0))) + vec3(equal(neighbours, vec3(3.0)));
 
    // fade the current pixel as it ages
    current -= vec3(greaterThan(current, vec3(0.4)))*0.05;
 
    // write out the pixel
    gl_FragColor = vec4(current, 1.0);
}
'''])
 
# bind our shader
shader.bind()
# set the correct texture unit
shader.uniformi('tex0', 0)
# unbind the shader
shader.unbind()
 
# create the texture
texture = pyglet.image.Texture.create(window.width, window.height, GL_RGBA)
 
# create a fullscreen quad
batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
batch.add(4, GL_QUADS, None, ('v2i', (0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1)), ('t2f', (0,0, 1.0,0, 1.0,1.0, 0,1.0)))
 
# utility function to copy the framebuffer into a texture
def copyFramebuffer(tex, *size):
    # if we are given a new size
    if len(size) == 2:
        # resize the texture to match
        tex.width, tex.height = size[0], size[1]
 
    # bind the texture
    glBindTexture(tex.target, tex.id)
    # copy the framebuffer
    glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 0, 0, tex.width, tex.height, 0);
    # unbind the texture
    glBindTexture(tex.target, 0)
 
# handle the window resize event
@window.event
def on_resize(width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    # setup a simple 0-1 orthoganal projection
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
 
    # copy the framebuffer, which also resizes the texture
    copyFramebuffer(texture, width, height)
 
    # bind our shader
    shader.bind()
    # set a uniform to tell the shader the size of a single pixel
    shader.uniformf('pixel', 1.0/width, 1.0/height)
    # unbind the shader
    shader.unbind()
 
    # tell pyglet that we have handled the event, to prevent the default handler from running
    return pyglet.event.EVENT_HANDLED
 
# clear the window and draw the scene
@window.event
def on_draw():
    # clear the screen
    window.clear()
 
    # bind the texture
    glBindTexture(texture.target, texture.id)
    # and the shader
    shader.bind()
 
    # draw our fullscreen quad
    batch.draw()
 
    # unbind the shader
    shader.unbind()
    # an the texture
    glBindTexture(texture.target, 0)
 
    # copy the result back into the texture
    copyFramebuffer(texture)
 
# schedule an empty update function, at 60 frames/second
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: None, 1.0/60.0)
 
# make the window visible
window.set_visible(True)
 
# finally, run the application
pyglet.app.run()
```

archivo 2: shader.py

```
#
# Copyright Tristam Macdonald 2008.
#
# Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0
# (see http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
#
from ctypes import *
#from ctypes import POINTER, byref, c_char, c_char_p, c_float, c_int, cast, create_string_buffer, pointer
from pyglet.gl import *

class Shader:
    # vert, frag and geom take arrays of source strings
    # the arrays will be concattenated into one string by OpenGL
    def __init__(self, vert = [], frag = [], geom = []):
        # create the program handle
        self.handle = glCreateProgram()
        # we are not linked yet
        self.linked = False

        # create the vertex shader
        self.createShader(vert, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        # create the fragment shader
        self.createShader(frag, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        # the geometry shader will be the same, once pyglet supports the extension
        # self.createShader(frag, GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER_EXT)

        # attempt to link the program
        self.link()

    def createShader(self, strings, type):
        count = len(strings)
        # if we have no source code, ignore this shader
        if count < 1:
            return

        # create the shader handle
        shader = glCreateShader(type)

        # convert the source strings into a ctypes pointer-to-char array, and upload them
        # this is deep, dark, dangerous black magick - don't try stuff like this at home!
        src_bytes = [s.encode() for s in strings]
        src = (c_char_p * count)(*src_bytes) 
        #src = (c_char_p * count)(*strings) #python 2
        print("hola mundo")
        
        glShaderSource(shader, count, cast(pointer(src), POINTER(POINTER(c_char))), None)

        # compile the shader
        glCompileShader(shader)

        temp = c_int(0)
        # retrieve the compile status
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, byref(temp))

        # if compilation failed, print the log
        if not temp:
            # retrieve the log length
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, byref(temp))
            # create a buffer for the log
            buffer = create_string_buffer(temp.value)
            # retrieve the log text
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, temp, None, buffer)
            # print the log to the console
            print (buffer.value)
        else:
            # all is well, so attach the shader to the program
            glAttachShader(self.handle, shader)

    def link(self):
        # link the program
        glLinkProgram(self.handle)

        temp = c_int(0)
        # retrieve the link status
        glGetProgramiv(self.handle, GL_LINK_STATUS, byref(temp))

        # if linking failed, print the log
        if not temp:
            #   retrieve the log length
            glGetProgramiv(self.handle, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, byref(temp))
            # create a buffer for the log
            buffer = create_string_buffer(temp.value)
            # retrieve the log text
            glGetProgramInfoLog(self.handle, temp, None, buffer)
            # print the log to the console
            print (buffer.value)
        else:
            # all is well, so we are linked
            self.linked = True

    def bind(self):
        # bind the program
        glUseProgram(self.handle)

    def unbind(self):
        # unbind whatever program is currently bound - not necessarily this program,
        # so this should probably be a class method instead
        glUseProgram(0)

    # upload a floating point uniform
    # this program must be currently bound
    def uniformf(self, name, *vals):
        # check there are 1-4 values
        if len(vals) in range(1, 5):
            # select the correct function
            { 1 : glUniform1f,
                2 : glUniform2f,
                3 : glUniform3f,
                4 : glUniform4f
                # retrieve the uniform location, and set
            }[len(vals)](glGetUniformLocation(self.handle, name), *vals)

    # upload an integer uniform
    # this program must be currently bound
    def uniformi(self, name, *vals):
        # check there are 1-4 values
        if len(vals) in range(1, 5):
            print(len(vals),vals,*vals,type(vals),type(*vals))
            # select the correct function
            { 1 : glUniform1i,
                2 : glUniform2i,
                3 : glUniform3i,
                4 : glUniform4i
                # retrieve the uniform location, and set
            }[len(vals)](glGetUniformLocation(self.handle, name), *vals)

    # upload a uniform matrix
    # works with matrices stored as lists,
    # as well as euclid matrices
    def uniform_matrixf(self, name, mat):
        # obtian the uniform location
        loc = glGetUniformLocation(self.Handle, name)
        # uplaod the 4x4 floating point matrix
        glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, False, (c_float * 16)(*mat))
```

Answer (score 1):

Me respondo a mí mismo. Lo he solucionado cambiando en archivo 1: opengl_prueba.py esta línea `shader.uniformi('tex0', 0)`por esta `shader.uniformi(b'tex0', 0)`y esta otra `shader.uniformf('pixel', 1.0/width, 1.0/height)`por esta `shader.uniformf(b'pixel', 1.0/width, 1.0/height)`. Esta parte la tengo solucionada pero tengo otro problema que expondré como nueva pregunta.

Comment: Si ya solucionaste tu problema anterior, debes responder netamente a esa pregunta, y crear una nueva con el nuevo problema que estás teniendo. Modifica tu respuesta para mejorarla en base a [answer], y no olvides [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: Hace algún tiempo que no hago preguntas y olvidé el protocolo. Gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).